# How can I make Visual Studio Code's auto-complete suggestions appear more quickly?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I have more than sufficient resources free:

[image]

but Visual Studio Code is taking several seconds to show an auto-completion list, even when I have typed 80% of what is to be completed.

How can I make Visual Studio Code's auto-complete suggestions appear more quickly?

Comment: a hyper threaded CPU is not as fast as a regular CPU. try again after rebooting and **only** VSC running, no internet and GPU activity. Is VSC running in the Virtual Machine?

Comment: I am not running a virtual machine. Nor is much running in the background. And just look at those free resources.

Comment: There is a `Quick Suggestions Delay` setting, but the default is 10ms - so that shouldn't be the issue unless it got changed.  Check it to see what it is set at.

Comment: It is at the default, 10ms :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that you have some VS code's extension enabled that is slowing down your system.
To check if that's the case open Command Palette (Ctrl+shift+p) and type  "Disable all installed extensions".
Check if the experience is faster and more responsive now. If that's the case now you need to find the extension that is slowing you, for doing so follow these steps:
open Command Palette (Ctrl+shift+p) and type  "Show Installed Extensions", now from the list you will have to spend some time activating and deactivating extensions until you find the one causing the troubles.

NOTE: You can show suggestions at any time pressing Ctrl+space and Ctrl+shift+space, so you can try forcing it when it's not showing.

Comment: Grrrr!! That was what I feared. I have disabled all and auto-complete is as quick as I could wish. Of course, it won't even run my app now, so I will slow start enabling & see which breaks it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An out of blue suggestion, but you can try light weight editors like Sublime text 3. The response time in auto-complete there is one of the best I have ever seen.

Comment: is it free, and does it support C/C++, PHP, Python, AngualrJs, HTML, CSS and Dart )with Ada as a bonus)? Including debugging, out of the box?

Comment: Its free, with some features kept for premium version. But free version has been helping me for 4+ years. It's a text editor so you can all the plugins you need. It does only syntax highlighting out of box. But overall it's very light and snappy and works fast even with large files. Definitely worth a try.

Comment: Its free, with some features kept for premium version. But free version has been helping me for 4+ years. It's a text editor so you can all the plugins you need. It does only syntax highlighting out of box. But overall it's very light and snappy and works fast even with large files. Definitely worth a try.

Comment: You can add debugging plugins. The whole editor has programmable settings here and there. Personally I never use dubug tools, so I can't share much experience.

Comment: I have been a professional s/w develop for a few decades now, and  cannot recommend the debugger highly enough. It is your best friend. Stop adding, then removing, print statements. Just set a "breakpoint", or several, run your code and it will stop when execution reaches a breakpoint. Then you can examine the call stack to see how you get there (even jump back up the call stack), examine parameters, variables and memory (and change their values, to see what happens), and step through your code, line by line, stepping over or into functions as you go -->

Comment: -->  Anyone who showed up at interview and said they don't/won't use a debugger would be shown the door - with good reason. Please, do yourself a favour and give it a try (just as I will try your recommendation +1)

Comment: Okay, I will try it out. Thanks. Also, I am a python programmer and primarily use Jupyter so that one is pretty clean and a breakpoint is easy.

Comment: Once you try the debugger, you will never look back :-) I have not tried Jupyter, so can't comment. At work we use [PyCharm community edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/). It is by far the best of all Python IDEs that I have tried so far. In fact, it is by JetBrains and I use 4 of their excellent IDEs (although only PyCharm is free - even for commercial use)