# Can I have multiple configurations of Visual Studio Code, one per coding language, each with its own plugins?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

This is ***not*** a duplicate of [How do I open multiple instances of Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964825/how-do-i-open-multiple-instances-of-visual-studio-code).

My previous question, [How can I make Visual Studio Code's auto-complete suggestions appear more quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062632/how-can-i-make-visual-studio-codes-auto-complete-suggestions-appear-more-quickl/62208047) explains my problem.

I was using VSC with the PlatformIo plugin for embedded development for a few months with no problem. Then I started on Flutter/Dart and soon had a problem with auto-suggest being ***really*** slow.

It ***could*** be that I just loaded a duff plug-in (I am adding them back, one by one, to see if/when it "breaks"), but ... I am considering doing all development in VCS, so as to have a single IDE.

I am currently using Eclipse for C/C++ and PHP, WebStorm for AngualrJs and PyCharm for Python.

I had previously used Eclipse for everything, and  had a different copy of Eclipse for each language, each with its own plugins.

Since I will be developing in 4 or 5 languages, even if I don't hit a problem as bad as I just did, adding plug-ins for that many languages into a single IDE will inevitably slow things down.

So, question: can I have multiple installs of VSC, each with its own plug-ins, and launch them separately?

Comment: you can disable extensions for particular workspaces, go to the extension page and use the dropdown at the top

Comment: Thanks, I knew that, but if I have multiple workspaces for one language, I don't want to enable/disable the same extensions for each workspace. I just want to do it once for each language, which is why I am thinking of a separate IDE, with language specific extensions, for each language.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's currently possible from what I could find, but there might be some suggestions in this issue that could help you https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40239

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem on windows using vs code portable.
I created a folder at the root of my machine with subfolders for each language, inside each I put the vs code, then I created a data folder inside each of them so that the information was stored locally, I modified the name of the executables and added it to the path.

As an example, to access a vscode configured for python I put code-python . at the terminal.

I Have the idea watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFPvnxIgwKA), it may help you (it is in portuguese, but you can see more os less what it does).

Answer (score 3):

See the menu \File\Preferences\Profiles.
It allows you to create, import, export VS Code profiles that includes a set of plugins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a great answer that would solve a LOT of questions across the web...